# Help with directories

Tags: javascript, readfile

I am running a java script in an .htm file located at /Dir1/Dir2/Dir3/testing.htm. Where it says script src=" " What would I put in the quotations to have it read from my file located at /Dir1/Test1/example.txt

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can put: `/Dir1/Test1/example.txt`

The slash at the beginning tells the browser use the base directory as a point of reference when looking for files.

You can also do `../../Test1/example.txt` which will look at the directory structure relative to your testing.htm file location.

Comment: But that still doesn't work because I have to back out 2 or 3 leves in the directory to get to /Dir1

Comment: Then you probably want to use the relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Or relative: ../../Test1/example.txt